# add mysql dependency configure.ac bitcoin

Tags: bitcoind, c++, mysql

i am working on bitcoin code, my aim is to move blockchain data to relational db but i am not able to resolve mysql dependency for different platform, platform includes mac and ubuntu. I have tried giving static and dynamic dependency but both of those things not working at all.

```
 [  --with-mysql=<path>     root directory path of MySQL installation],
    [MYSQL_lib_check="$with_mysql/lib/mysql $with_mysql/lib"
MYSQL_inc_check="$with_mysql/include/mysql"],
    [MYSQL_lib_check="/usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql /usr/local/lib/mysql /opt/mysql/lib/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /usr/local/mysql/lib /usr/local/lib /opt/mysql/lib /usr/lib"
MYSQL_inc_check="/usr/local/mysql/include/mysql /usr/local/include/mysql /opt/mysql/include/mysql /usr/include/mysql"])

AC_ARG_WITH(mysql-lib,
    [  --with-mysql-lib=<path> directory path of MySQL library installation],
    [MYSQL_lib_check=$with_mysql/lib/mysql])

AC_ARG_WITH(mysql-include,
    [  --with-mysql-include=<path>
                          directory path of MySQL header installation],
    [MYSQL_inc_check=$with_mysql/include/mysql])

AC_MSG_CHECKING([for MySQL library directory])
MYSQL_libdir=
for m in $MYSQL_lib_check; do
        if test -d "$m" && \
       (test -f "$m/libmysqlclient.so" || test -f "$m/libmysqlclient.a")
        then
                MYSQL_libdir=$m
                break
        fi
done
```

while configuring i was trying to gave path of installation directory i.e ./configure --with-mysql=/path it configured successfully but when i execute make command it throws exception "_get_driver_instance", referenced from: makeConnection() in libbitcoin_wallet.a(libbitcoin_wallet_a-walletdb.o)

might be i am not on right track, help me if you have any idea regarding make file system

any help is appreciable, thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There’s no performance or really any value in doing so.

Comment: its just for learning purpose to manage huge amount of records through DBMS.

Comment: Just in general, you'l struggle with this. The data is absolutely colossal and largely a single key value store. Almost the entire CPU time of bitcoin core other than ECDSA validation is doing key insertions.

Comment: i am going to do insertion and related stuff after block validation is done